# Merge array items into new array based on array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, async.js

I have an array containing stories, each story also has a "day", I'd like to be able to merge stories on the same "day" into a new array.

```
stories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        day: '18-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: //JSON containing a single story + other data
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        day: '18-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: //JSON containing a single story + other data
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        day: '17-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: //JSON containing a single story + other data
    }

]
```

Here is what I'd like my output array to look like:

```
feed = [
    {
        day: '18-02-2017',
        stories: [
            //multiple JSON story items
        ]
    },
    {
        day: '17-02-2017',
        stories: [
            //multiple JSON story items
        ]
    }

]
```

I'm using the Async library in NodeJS for the necessary FOR loops since I also need to work with the data asynchronously before it's added to this final array - I understand what needs to happen to make the new array it's just been going completely over my head how to put it into code.

Comment: The user id value is of no importance?

Comment: @trincot It's not, I just wanted to demonstrate there is other data in the array. I suppose I could have just left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a single loop with a closure over a hash table.

```js
var stories = [{ id: 1, day: '18-02-2017', user: 1, story_data: '01' }, { id: 2, day: '18-02-2017', user: 1, story_data: '02' }, { id: 3, day: '17-02-2017', user: 1, story_data: '03' }],
    result = stories.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.day]) {
                hash[a.day] = { day: a.day, stories: [] };
                r.push(hash[a.day]);
            }
            hash[a.day].stories.push(a);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, my God this is amazing. If you would like to describe what did you do here...

Comment: @Kinduser, it uses an object and the `day` as key and an object as value, where the stories get collected inside the `stories` property. that is the part for the hash table. the other part is to get the wanted output in an array. this is handled with an array and a check if the day exists in the hash table. if not, generate the hast table object and push the same object to the result array. this keeps the reference to the collected stories and the hash table with the day. when you now have a hash with the day, you yould add the story to it. voilà.

Comment: Thanks for it. But, I don't get one more thing, what is the point of adding `if (!hash[a.day]){}` and what does it... does?

Comment: @Kinduser, it checks if the day exists in the hash table ... that what i wrote above.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. By the way - your answers are like a neverending river of knowledge. You should print them and sell like a books or something xd

Answer (score 2):

```
function groupByDay(arr) {
  var hash = arr.reduce(function(h, s) {                   // h is the hash object, s is the current story
    h[s.day] = h[s.day] || {'day': s.day, 'stories': []};  // if the hash doesn't have an entry for this story's day, then add it
    h[s.day].stories.push(s);                              // add this story to the stories array of the object that acummulates the result for this day
    return h;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(hash).map(function(key) {             // unwrap the objects from the hash object and return them as an array (the result)
    return hash[key];
  });
}
```

Here is the MDN docs for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 2):

Try running this code:

```
var jsonStories = {};
stories.forEach(function(story) {
    if (!jsonStories[story['day']]) {
        jsonStories[story['day']] = {
            'day': story['day'],
            'stories': []
        };
    }
    jsonStories[story['day']]['stories'].push(story);
});
var storiesArr = [];
Object.keys(jsonStories).forEach(function(key) {
    storiesArr.push(jsonStories[key]);
});
```

You will get an ordered array.
You can also get it as JSON array if you remove the four last rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
let day2story = {};

stories.forEach((story) => {
  let curr = day2story[story.day] || [];
  curr.push(story.story_data);
  day2story[story.day] = curr;
});

let feed = [];

Object.keys(day2story).forEach((day) => feed.push({day: day, stories: day2story[day]}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(feed))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 code:

```
const result = Array.from(
    stories.reduce( 
        (acc, {day, story_data}) => acc.set(day, (acc.get(day) || []).concat(story_data)),
        new Map
    ),
    ([day, story_data]) => ({day, story_data})
);
```

```js
const stories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        day: '18-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: "story1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        day: '18-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: "story2"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        day: '17-02-2017',
        user: 1,
        story_data: "story3"
    }
];

const result = Array.from(
    stories.reduce( 
        (acc, {day, story_data}) => acc.set(day, (acc.get(day) || []).concat(story_data)),
        new Map
    ),
    ([day, story_data]) => ({day, story_data})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

The `reduce` method creates a `Map`, keyed by the dates, and with the corresponding story arrays as values. So if the key does not yet exist in the map, an empty array is taken (`|| []`), otherwise its current value, and then the new story is added to it.

The map returned by `reduce` would in itself be a nice structure to work with, but as you asked for an array of objects, `Array.from` is applied to that map. This results in an array of pairs (sub-arrays with key / value entries), but `Array.from` accepts a callback function with which this pair can be transformed into the object with 2 properties.

This solution uses arrow functions, destructuring and `Map` which are all ES6 features.

Comment: :-) Yes, too many parentheses and braces. Lisp-like, haha. But you like it too -- I have seen some very lamda-like answers from you as well :P

Comment: does there exist some style guide for it?

Comment: I suppose one should put parentheses following the rules for braces. I updated the format a bit.